# Логирование стороннего приложения

Tags: python

Могу ли я с помощью python получать все изменения процесса? Как бы логировать каждое новое событие в процессе/приложении?

Пример: Убит юнит в игре, я это узнал по бесконечному логу который формируется у меня из прослушки процесса.(или как это назвать) Вывел время когда он возродится.

Comment: Что значит стороннее? Ваше же приложение на питоне? Или вообще случайный процесс?

Comment: Лог это файл или вам нужно каким то образом подключиться к процессу?

Comment: @dlm0n случайный процесс.

Comment: @5c0rp к процессу.